Error en ingreso de datos
Buen día.
Estoy tratando de escribir un código que tome como argumento una tupla y me retorne la misma, con sus elementos en orden inverso. Me sale así como muestra la imagen. ¿Alguien sabe en qué me estoy equivocando? Gracias.

Este es el código:


Pon siempre el código como texto, con formato. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

El problema es que no haces la transformación correctamente. El constructor de la clase lista crea una lista nueva a partir de un iterable lo que resulta en una lista de caracteres.

Si sigues paso a paso las operaciones que realizas te darás cuenta de donde está el problema.
He aquí una solución:
string_entrada = input("Ingrese la tupla ")
sin_comas = string_entrada.replace(',', '')
lista = sin_comas.split()
print("Entrada como lista", lista)
lista.reverse()
print("Lista reversada", lista)

Paso a paso
string_entrada = input("Ingrese la tupla ")

La función input() siempre retorna un string; llamar el resultado tupla1 induce a errores.
sin_comas = string_entrada.replace(',', '')

De ese string hay que eliminar las comas, pues no las quieres en el resultado. Eso se hace con la método replace() que busca el primer argumento y lo reemplace con el segundo en todo el string, dejandonos "2 6 98"
lista = sin_comas.split()

Con split() dividimos el string en partes separadas por espacios. El resultado es una lista de esas partes.
lista.reverse()

Finalmente, con el método reverse() damos vuelta la lista.
Demo
La ejecución produce
Ingrese la tupla 2, 6, 98
Entrada como lista ['2', '6', '98']
Lista reversada ['98', '6', '2']

Process finished with exit code 0


Muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

@VictorVacca aca la forma de agradecer es puntuar las respuestas, y por supuesto, aceptarlas si sirvieron

Estimado, ¿cómo puntúo una respuesta? Soy nuevo en esto gracias.

Ya la marcaste como aceptada; eso cuenta como puntaje. Puedes darle un punto a cualquier respuesta (aceptada o no) usando la flecha arriba (a la izquierda de la respuesta). También puedes quitar un punto con la flecha abajo.
